# Thick ticks are cut off

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I want thick ticks but the 1st and last ticks are cut. It seems that the figure is cut exactly at axis boundaries so the thick ticks are cut off and look thiner than it others. Could someone tell me how to fix it please ?

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
axis equal image,
xmin=0., xmax=4, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
xlabel={centimètres}, ylabel={},
xlabel style={yshift=10pt},
axis x line*=middle, axis y line=none,
xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
major tick length=10pt,
minor tick length=5pt,
major x tick style={thick, color=black},
minor x tick num={9},
xticklabels={},
xtick align=center,
axis on top,
width=0.9\textwidth
]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```